# Designing an algorithm: arrange rectangles of varying sizes, in a pre-defined order, into an approximate box

Tags: algorithms

Given:
 - List of rectangles (height x width).
 - Maximum width and height of result.

Arrange the rectangles, without changing the order of the list, to be as close to a square as possible.  The items should go top down, left to right.  If all items can't fit within the width and height result, then ignore the max width.

Example 1: A list of squares: 1, 2, 3, 4, would be arranged as:

```
1 3
2 4
```

Example 2: A list of squares, except #2 is a rectangle with twice the height:

```
1 3
2 4
2 5
```

Example 3: A list of squares, except #2 is a rectangle with twice the width:

```
1   4
2 2 5
3   6
```

Obviously the real applications are not that neat, and shouldn't be expected to form perfect final results, just get as close as reasonably possible.  Performance is not critical, but it can't be terrible as this will be run every frame (so brute forcing is too much).  "Reasonably close" results that capture the spirit are fine - if a human couldn't immediately spot an improvement to be made it's adequate.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: I don't see what's left to optimise -- there seems to only ever be one action available, "Try to fit it beneath the previous one with its left edge aligned with the previous one's left edge, but if that exceeds max height, then start a new column instead".

Comment: @j_random_hacker That could lead to undesired results though.  Eg with 9 squares to sort, the ideal is a 3x3 grid.  However if the max height is set to 4, you’d get 4,4,1.  If the max height was higher, like 8, that gets even worse.  Also, changing the contents if each column will change the highest width of that column, and thus will alter the net width of the entire result...

Comment: I think I see. So I think one thing you could do is to simply try my above algorithm for many different heights that are less than or equal to the max height, and see which one leaves you with height closest to width. (Unfortunately binary search on the height *won't* guarantee an optimal result here, because it's possible that making the height shorter actually decreases the total width, e.g. if it forces two wide rectangles that were in different columns into the same column so that you only "pay for" them once.)